# Getting Error: (-215:Assertion failed) When Using seamlessClone

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

For clarity, I am a beginner in Python. I'm creating a script that replaces the eyes with a robotic one from a series of images in a folder. I'm stuck on the seamlessClone function that keeps throwing this error.

The code is incomplete as far as writing out the entire script (it only clones one eye so far), but everything should be working. I've been stuck on this one for 6 hours and thought I would ask on here.

I've tried checking my filenames, paths, seeing if the image file was corrupt by using print, changing the image files with different dimensions, filetypes (png, jpg) and so on.

I've also tried converting every numpy array(cv2_image, Eye) into a 32bit array to see if that was the issue, but nothing prevailed.

```
# Import

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
from statistics import mean
import face_recognition
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np


# Open Eye Images

Eye = cv2.imread('eye.jpg')

# Loop Through Images

for filename in glob.glob('images/*.jpg'):

    cv2_image = cv2.imread(filename)
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(filename)
    face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)
    for facemarks in face_landmarks_list:

        # Get Eye Data
        eyeLPoints = facemarks['left_eye']
        eyeRPoints = facemarks['right_eye']
        npEyeL = np.array(eyeLPoints)
        npEyeR = np.array(eyeRPoints)

        # Create Mask

        mask = np.zeros(cv2_image.shape, cv2_image.dtype)
        mask.fill(0)
        poly = np.array([eyeLPoints])
        cv2.fillPoly(mask, [poly], (255,255, 255))

        # Get Eye Image Centers 

        npEyeL = np.array(eyeLPoints)
        eyeLCenter = npEyeL.mean(axis=0).astype("int")
        x1 = (eyeLCenter[0])
        x2 = (eyeLCenter[1])
        print(x1, x2)

        # Get Head Rotation (No code yet)

        # Apply Seamless Clone To Main Image
        saveImage = cv2.seamlessClone(Eye, cv2_image, mask ,(x1, x2) , cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)

# Output and Save

cv2.imwrite('output/output.png', saveImage)
```

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 45, in <module>
    saveImage = cv2.seamlessClone(Eye, cv2_image, mask ,(x1, x2) , cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:466: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function 'Mat'
```

The result I'm expecting is for the eye image to be cloned onto the original image, but this error keeps being thrown, preventing me from completing the script. If there were any hint as to what's going on, I feel that the culprit is the "Eye" file, but I could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sets of keypoints:

- There is a set of keypoints for the eye in the destination image:
  [image: keypoints dst image]
- There is a set of keypoints for the eye in the source image:
  [image: keypoints source image]

You are using the wrong set of keypoints to make the mask for the  `cv2.seamlessClone()` function. You should be using the keypoints from the source image. The mask needs to be a TWO channel image, in your code (among the other problems) you are using a THREE channel image.

This is the result. You can see there should also be a resize function to match the sizes of the eyes:

[image: output]

This is the code that I used:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open Eye Images
eye = cv2.imread('eye.jpg')

# Open Face image
face = cv2.imread('face.jpeg')
# Get Keypoints
image = face_recognition.load_image_file('face.jpeg')
face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(image)
for facemarks in face_landmarks_list:
    # Get Eye Data
    eyeLPoints = facemarks['left_eye']
    eyeRPoints = facemarks['right_eye']
    npEyeL = np.array(eyeLPoints)

# These points define the contour of the eye in the EYE image
poly_left = np.array([(51, 228), (100, 151), (233, 102), (338, 110), (426, 160), (373, 252), (246, 284), (134, 268)], np.int32)

# Create a mask for the eye
src_mask = np.zeros(face.shape, face.dtype)
cv2.fillPoly(src_mask, [poly_left], (255, 255, 255))
cv2.imwrite('src_mask.png', src_mask)
# Find where the eye should go
center, r = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(npEyeL)
center = tuple(np.array(center, int))
# Clone seamlessly.
output = cv2.seamlessClone(eye, face, src_mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I can't believe I've overlooked that, because initially I was going to create a mask around the eye, and paste the eye image behind the source image. I guess I was too caught up in my old script.

I do have a question though.

"(among the other problems) " Could you possibly provide a bit of clarity on this?

Comment: Sure! Glad I could help. There were three problems (1) the mask was three channel instead of two, (2) the wrong set of keypoints was being used, and (3) there needs to be some resizing to make the size of the source eye match the destination eye.